# Making a k-map from an equation

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

I understand kmaps and I know how to make one from an equation in sum-of-products form. For example, `w'x'y'z + w'x'yz`. But I don't know what to do when some of the products don't contain all variables in play. For example `w'x'y' + wx'y'z'`. Do you fill in each grid space that contains that product (for the first product in the earlier example, w'x'y'z and w'x'y'z')? Or do you have to do some boolean algebra, or something else?

Comment: You've got it right. It is because `A = AB+AB'`. To make it visual, try looking at the truth table of the two.

Comment: I've always pictured this as "which squares match up with `w'x'y'`?" There can be more than one square to fill in. nidhin's answer is much more rigorous and you might prefer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. The first step is to express the SOP in its [canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form).*

It means that each term in the SOP must be the product of four variables. 
In order to make so, multiply (AND) each term with `(m+m')` where m is the missing variable. If more than one variables (`m`, `n`, `o` ...) are absent in the term, then multiply with `(m+m')(n+n')(o+o') ....`

Considering your example, `w'x'y' + wx'y'z'`, the first term is missing `z` in it. So multiply by `(z+z')`.

`w'x'y' + wx'y'z' = w'x'y'(z'+z) + wx'y'z' = w'x'y'z' + w'x'y'z + wx'y'z'`

*2. Then put 1 in the K-map cells corresponding to these minterms.* *ie.,* (0,1,8).

Similarly, logical expressions in POS can be converted into canonical form and filling corresponding maxterms in K-map with '0' will also give you the result.